# Presentation of handlebody mapping class group

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mapping-class-groups, presentations-of-groups

I know some 'nice' infinite presentations of the mapping class group of a surface, such as Gervais' and Luo's. By 'nice' I mean that generators and relations belong to a small number of families.

Is there a 'nice' (infinite) presentation of the handlebody mapping class group, in the same spirit? I just know very complicated finite presentations, such as Wajnryb's and Hirose's, and I do not really care about finiteness.

Comment: I don’t know of one in the literature, but I basically know how to go about finding one given a good enough incentive (eg a nice application).  What is your motivation?

Comment: I had an application in mind, but my reasoning was wrong